# Apparently I marked a question as duplicate, except I didn't

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688653/when-to-use-arrow-functions-instead-of-regular-functions-in-utils) was marked as duplicate, apparently by me:

[image]

But I never marked it as a duplicate, I did add a close vote due to being "primarily opinion-based", in my opinion:

[image]

Is that a bug or does it throw all close votes into a bucket when a decision is made?

Comment: Did you upvote a comment saying `possible duplicate of .....`?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Nope, that would have shown on my votes cast, and it doesn't

Comment: If someone with a binding close vote casts a vote - that becomes the close reason and the reason shown for everyone... (There's some more details elsewhere on how that works...). In this case - there were 3 POB votes and then David's binding vote caused it to end up a duplicate.